# Selecting an element from a dropdown using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a DROPDOWN LIST and it doesn't have the select attribute:

[image]

```
    <ul id="Registration_RegistrationStateCode_listbox" class="k-list k-reset" unselectable="on" style="overflow: auto; height: 200px;" tabindex="-1" role="listbox" aria-hidden="false" aria-live="off">
<li id="Registration_RegistrationStateCode_option_selected" class="k-item k-state-selected k-state-focused" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="true">-- Select State --</li>
<li class="k-item" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Alabama</li>
<li class="k-item" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Alaska</li>
<li class="k-item" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Arizona</li>
<li class="k-item" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Arkansas</li>
<li class="k-item" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">California</li>
<li class="k-item" unselectable="on" role="option" tabindex="-1">Colorado</li>
```

How to select a particular state?

I am unable to select any state as it does not have select tag.

Comment: Do you use the Page Object Model in your framework?

Comment: no framework. simple practice using driver.findElemnt

Comment: `//*[text()='Alabama']` you can click dropdown using XPATH too and call click() on element.

Comment: it worked in chrome but faailed in ie

Comment: @heardm after doing get() operation you have to wait until elements are loaded on browser for now you can add sleep after doing get() but usually implicit wait or explicit wait is recommended.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the Page Object Model, I would create a function in this specific Page Object such as the following:

```
        public void SelectState(string state)
        {
            _driver.FindElement(By.Id("Registration_RegistrationStateCode_listbox")).Click();
            _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[text()='" + state + "']")).Click();
        }
```

Otherwise you can just use the individual lines and pass in a state:

```
_driver.FindElement(By.Id("Registration_RegistrationStateCode_listbox")).Click();
_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[text()='Minnesota']")).Click();
```

Comment: You might want to limit your search on the `LI` to only those inside the specific `UL`. If it's a page that has a lot of elements, one of the elements may contains state names also. Just to be safe...